# Encountered a calculation bug (?) while writing a simple program on python 3

Tags: python-3.x, input

Just have started learning how to code on python. And I wrote a simple program with calcutation, then I've encountered a bug (well I'm not sure if I should call it a bug). Please, explain me what went wrong, and why did I get such a strange result, and how to fix it?

here is the code

```
[num1 = input('Enter a number: ')
num2 = input('Enter another number: ')
result = float(num1) + float(num2)

print(result)][1]
```

input 1st = 2.2
input 2nd = 1.1
result : 3.3000000000000003

Answer (score 0):

To settle your issue you can use round() in the first parameter give the float number and the second parameter the number you would take after the dot.

```
num1 = input('Enter a number: ')
num2 = input('Enter another number: ')
result = float(num1) + float(num2)

print(round(result, 2)) #round(0.123456, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer.. At least, now I know how to fix that.